# Email address included in profile export despite promise not to

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

For Stack Overflow Careers:

Going into "edit profile" mode and clicking the first edit link leads to various personal details, including email address. The "email address" field, when active, has a message:

> Your email address is not displayed on your profile.
>   We only use this to send you notifications and such.

However, if you use either the "create pdf" or "create markdown" functions, they will include this email address at the top of the page, and I tested that it changes when you edit this field.

Should either the message or the functionality be altered? I was surprised to see my "generic internet" email account appear on the exports despite this assurance.

(neat feature, though!)

Comment: Are you talking about Stack Overflow Careers?

Comment: Oh dear, I am. Terribly sorry, thought I'd found the right site and was too hasty to write the report.

Comment: It's fine to post about Careers here, it just wasn't clear if that was what you meant. AFAIK, those buttons are not accessible to anyone but you.

Comment: Probably not, but I'm wondering if someone might miss it and submit a document with an email address they didn't think would be published.

Comment: I assume the create PDF/Markdown features are to make yourself a printable version of your résumé, in which case it seems normal to include your email as that's the only way to contact you.

Comment: I agree that it should be available, but the data it uses is not necessarily provided with the expectation of publishing (as in my case) - it's likely an OpenID.

Comment: That's not a bug. The export buttons appear only to you, and you're the only one who can use them. Other people viewing your profile can't use such buttons and can't see your email address.

Answer (score 14):

This isn't a bug. If you request a PDF or your resume, with the intention to send it, there should be some information for people you send it to to contact you, isn't it? This information is not provided to others than you and SE, as made very clear in the privacy policy:

> That said, your contact information (email, phone, and address) will not be provided to employers in their candidate searches. We will only allow employers to have access to your contact information in two cases, both of which are under your control:
>
> - If you apply directly for a specific job, you will be asked to provide your name and email address (and other optional information) to the employer
> - If an employer finds you through a search and wants to contact you, we will ask if you are interested in hearing from them, and if you are, we will then provide them with your contact information.

*If* you send your resume to someone else, it is information you provide, not Stack Exchange. Feel free to make your own resume. You don't *have* to use this resume, you *can*.

Comment: I get what you mean about choosing to publish it yourself, but I feel it's in violation of "We only use this to send you notifications and such.". It's not internal-only data and I didn't notice anything to say that. That said, it's a relatively minor concern.

Comment: It is visible on your profile right? To whom is it available more? Do you expect them to put it in a basement or so?

Comment: @David it's the same as the fact that email is displayed in your profile when you view yourself while logged in.